# How to select rows and compute adjacent row's values in python pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have some data like follow structure. It used in python pandas Data Frame and I named it df.

```
Data1,Data2,Value
2016-04-29,00:40:15,3
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2
2016-04-29,00:40:35,2
2016-04-29,00:40:36,2
2016-04-29,00:40:43,2
2016-04-29,00:40:45,2
2016-04-29,00:40:55,1
```

I want to filter the data for the following conditions:

1. `df['Value'] <= 2`
2. `df.row['Data2'] - df.former_row['Data2'] > 10`  (former_row means the prior row. I don't know how to solve in python pandas. )

The result is like following.

```
Data1,Data2,Value
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2
2016-04-29,00:40:35,2
2016-04-29,00:40:43,2
2016-04-29,00:40:55,1
```

How can I used the function in pandas to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you explain more `former_row` ?

Comment: @Kartik - it looks like more complicated, simple diff doesnt get desired output.

Comment: Your expected results are inconsistent with the conditions you've laid out.  `2016-04-29,00:40:24,2` should not be selected as it is only 9 seconds from `2016-04-29,00:40:15,3`.  Neither should `2016-04-29,00:40:43,2` be selected as it's one 8 seconds from `2016-04-29,00:40:35,2`

Comment: @jezrael, You are right. Flag retracted. From OP's expected output, it appears that OP wants only those rows which are more than 10s apart from the previous row. `row[0]` is disqualified by condition 1; `row[1]` is the first valid row, so in output; `row[2] > row[1] + 10s`, in output; `row[3] < row[2] + 10s`, disqualified; `row[4]` this logic goes to hell...

Comment: @jezrael please approve kartik's edit

Comment: @piRSquared - done.

Comment: Maybe the OP wants *at most* one entry per 10 sec (not sliding) window. This would explain why `2016-04-29,00:40:36,2` and `2016-04-29,00:40:45,2` were excluded, but not the others. It could also be 10 sec from the *previously matched* entry. Anyway, the definition of `former_row` would solve this issue I guess.

Comment: @jezrael The former_row is not the function in DataFrame. It meas the previous row.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you so much. I have made a stupid mistake.

Comment: @piRSquared, @3kt, feels like we are playing darts with guessing the definition of `former_row`. @Chauncey, please explain what you expect to see when you compute `df.row['Data2'] - df.former_row['Data2']` for each `row` of your DataFrame. That would define `former_row` to us better than a 1000 words.

Answer (score 1):

Just to ensure we are working with the same setup:

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """Data1,Data2,Value
2016-04-29,00:40:15,3
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2
2016-04-29,00:40:35,2
2016-04-29,00:40:36,2
2016-04-29,00:40:43,2
2016-04-29,00:40:45,2
2016-04-29,00:40:55,1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep=',')
df.Data1 = pd.to_datetime(df.Data1)
df.Data2 = pd.to_timedelta(df.Data2)
```

IIUC:

```
cond1 = df.Value <= 2
cond2 = df.Data2.dt.total_seconds().diff() > 10

df.loc[cond1 & cond2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @piRsquared. Could you help me the other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910438/how-to-deal-with-this-complex-logic-in-python-pandas   It is more complex and I could not find the solution.

Comment: @Chauncey did my post here answer this question?  If so, it's usually customary to mark it as the answer.  It would be your choice to upvote in addition.  I'll look at the other question.