# How to deal with this complex logic in python pandas？

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have some data like follow structure. It used in python pandas Data Frame and I named it df.

```
Data1,Data2,Flag
2016-04-29,00:40:15,1
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2
2016-04-29,00:40:35,2
2015-04-29,00:40:36,2
2015-04-29,00:40:43,2
2015-04-29,00:40:45,2
2015-04-29,00:40:55,1
2015-04-29,00:41:05,1
2015-04-29,00:41:16,1
2015-04-29,00:41:17,2
.....................
.....................
2016-11-29,11:52:36,2
2016-11-29,11:52:43,2
2016-11-29,11:52:45,2
2016-11-29,11:52:55,1
```

I want to get the data meet the following requirements.

1. As you know the first data's timeseries is `2016-04-29,00:40:15`. I want to get the next data in this dataframe larger than primer's data 18 secs.
   I'll get the second data : `2016-04-29,00:40:35,2`
   The third data is: `2015-04-29,00:40:55,1`
2. If the next data's flag is different from the primer's data.I will get this data regardless of whether it has passed 18 secs.

For the above two requirements, I 'll get the data as following:

```
Data1,Data2,Flag
2016-04-29,00:40:15,1
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2
2015-04-29,00:40:43,2
2015-04-29,00:40:55,1
2015-04-29,00:41:16,1
2015-04-29,00:41:17,2
.....................
```

Answer (score 2):

I built a generator to produce the rows then used `pd.concat`

```
def get_row(df):
    ref = None
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if ref is not None:
            cond1 = (row.Data2.total_seconds() - 
                     ref.Data2.total_seconds() > 18)
            cond2 = row.Flag != ref.Flag
        if ref is None or cond1 or cond2:
            yield row
            ref = row

pd.concat([r for r in get_row(df)], axis=1).T
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

*Because @Kartik insisted :-)*

[image]

Comment: I have a better method! Working on it. Almost done... Trying to figure out what the OP's second requirement actually means.

Comment: Yes, sir. Your answer is a good 6 times faster than mine, on my machine. Plus, you beat me to answering it. But I insist that my answer looks better, concise... :-P

Comment: @Kartik I will give you the aesthetics prize... hands down.

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this:

```
df['Data2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Data2'])

tdf = df.copy()
sel_idx = []
while len(tdf) > 0:
    sel_idx.extend([tdf.index[0]])
    cond1 = tdf['Data2'] > tdf.loc[sel_idx[-1], 'Data2'] + pd.to_timedelta(18, 's')
    cond2 = (tdf['Flag'] != tdf.loc[sel_idx[-1], 'Flag']) & (tdf['Data2'] > tdf.loc[sel_idx[-1], 'Data2'])
    tdf = tdf[cond1 | cond2]
df.loc[sel_idx, :]
```

---

## Test

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Data1,Data2,Flag
2016-04-29,00:40:15,1
2016-04-29,00:40:24,2
2016-04-29,00:40:35,2
2015-04-29,00:40:36,2
2015-04-29,00:40:43,2
2015-04-29,00:40:45,2
2015-04-29,00:40:55,1
2015-04-29,00:41:05,1
2015-04-29,00:41:16,1
2015-04-29,00:41:17,2
2016-11-29,11:52:36,2
2016-11-29,11:52:43,2
2016-11-29,11:52:45,2
2016-11-29,11:52:55,1""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)
df['Data2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Data2'])
print("Input\n", df)

tdf = df.copy()
sel_idx = []
while len(tdf) > 0:
    sel_idx.extend([tdf.index[0]])
    cond1 = tdf['Data2'] > tdf.loc[sel_idx[-1], 'Data2'] + pd.to_timedelta(18, 's')
    cond2 = (tdf['Flag'] != tdf.loc[sel_idx[-1], 'Flag']) & (tdf['Data2'] > tdf.loc[sel_idx[-1], 'Data2'])
    tdf = tdf[cond1 | cond2]
print("Ouput\n", df.loc[sel_idx, :])
```

Output:

```
Input
    Data1       Data2       Flag
0   2016-04-29  00:40:15    1
1   2016-04-29  00:40:24    2
2   2016-04-29  00:40:35    2
3   2015-04-29  00:40:36    2
4   2015-04-29  00:40:43    2
5   2015-04-29  00:40:45    2
6   2015-04-29  00:40:55    1
7   2015-04-29  00:41:05    1
8   2015-04-29  00:41:16    1
9   2015-04-29  00:41:17    2
10  2016-11-29  11:52:36    2
11  2016-11-29  11:52:43    2
12  2016-11-29  11:52:45    2
13  2016-11-29  11:52:55    1

Output
    Data1       Data2       Flag
0   2016-04-29  00:40:15    1
1   2016-04-29  00:40:24    2
4   2015-04-29  00:40:43    2
6   2015-04-29  00:40:55    1
8   2015-04-29  00:41:16    1
9   2015-04-29  00:41:17    2
10  2016-11-29  11:52:36    2
13  2016-11-29  11:52:55    1
```