# Why do I get null values from conditional statement?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Thanks again for your patience, I am not the best communicator.  Please let me know if there is any additional information that I should add.

My current data looks like:

```
"Identifier","Status","OPENED","Resolv","closed_on","duplicate_on","junked_on","unproducible_on","verified_on"
"xx1","D","2004-07-28","","","2004-08-26","","",""
"xx2","N","2010-03-02","","","","","",""
"xx3","U","2005-10-26","","","","","2005-11-01",""
"xx4","V","2006-06-30","2006-09-15","","","","","2006-11-20"
"xx5","R","2012-09-21","2013-06-06","","","","",""
"xx6","D","2009-11-25","","","2010-02-26","","",""
"xx7","D","2003-08-29","","","2003-08-29","","",""
"xx8","R","2003-06-06","2003-06-24","","","","",""
"xx9","R","2004-11-05","2004-11-15","","","","",""
"xx10","R","2008-02-21","2008-09-25","","","","",""
"xx11","R","2007-03-08","2007-03-21","","","","",""
"xx12","R","2011-08-22","2012-06-21","","","","",""
"xx13","J","2003-07-07","","","","2003-07-10","",""
"xx14","A","2008-09-24","","","","","",""
```

I am trying to add an age calculation column using the code below so that the data looks like(notice that the first value is returning "" for age, this is what I am trying to solve with my question.  If the status does not have a date, then I want to use today's date.):

```
"Identifier","Status","OPENED","Resolv","closed_on","duplicate_on","junked_on","unproducible_on","verified_on","Age"
"xx1","J","2002-02-07","","","","","","",""
"xx2","J","2008-11-25","","","","2008-12-04","","",9.0
"xx3","C","2002-01-27","","2002-03-19","","","","",51.0
"xx4","V","2003-07-09","2003-07-10","","","","","2003-07-15",6.0
"xx5","D","2008-06-30","","","2008-09-09","","","",71.0
"xx6","R","2010-06-02","2010-06-11","","","","","",9.0
"xx7","R","2006-11-16","2006-12-12","","","","","",26.0
"xx8","R","2006-03-29","2006-03-31","","","","","",2.0
"xx9","R","2010-09-07","2010-10-05","","","","","",28.0
"xx10","U","2006-03-09","","","","","2006-06-20","",103.0
"xx11","R","2007-04-26","2007-05-01","","","","","",5.0
"xx12","C","2010-03-07","","2010-03-11","","","","",4.0
"xx13","R","2009-12-22","2010-05-31","","","","","",160.0
"xx14","R","2006-06-24","2006-06-28","","","","","",4.0
```

However, when defects are missing status change date, the age function returns '' as seen below in picture.  This is the case for all 102 blank cells.

[image: Missing data example]

```
from datetime import datetime as dtt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
```

Age column calculation function

```
def defect_age(df):
    """Performs age calc and creates age col"""
    today = dtt.today()
```

List of terminal statuses:

```
    terminal = ['R', 'V', 'D', 'J', 'U', 'C']
```

Date to date time per status

```
    resolved = pd.to_datetime(df.Resolv, errors='coerce')
    closed = pd.to_datetime(df.closed_on, errors='coerce')
    duplicate = pd.to_datetime(df.duplicate_on, errors='coerce')
    junked = pd.to_datetime(df.junked_on, errors='coerce')
    unproducible = pd.to_datetime(df.unproducible_on, errors='coerce')
    verified = pd.to_datetime(df.verified_on, errors='coerce')
    submitted = pd.to_datetime(df.OPENED, errors='coerce')
```

Date calculation by status

```
    r = (resolved - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D', errors='coerce')
    c = (closed - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D', errors='coerce')
    d = (duplicate - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D', errors='coerce')
    j = (junked - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D', errors='coerce')
    u = (unproducible - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D', errors='coerce')
    v = (verified - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D', errors='coerce')
    # not terminal state
    s = (today - submitted) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D', errors='coerce')
    date_calc = int(s)
```

I am trying to populate age column.  If status is terminal and date not blank use above date calculation.  For some reason when terminal states are blank, it is not using the else clause which is what I am trying to do.

```
    if df.Status in terminal:
        if df.Status == 'R' and df.Resolv != '':
            return r
        elif df.Status == 'C' and df.closed_on != '':
            return c
        elif df.Status == 'D' and df.duplicate_on != '':
            return d
        elif df.Status == 'J' and df.junked_on != '':
            return j
        elif df.Status == 'U' and df.unproducible_on != '':
            return u
        elif df.Status == 'V' and df.verified_on != '':
            return v
    else:
        return date_calc
```

Read in data

```
df = pd.read_csv('BigData.txt', low_memory=False)
```

Create new column using defect_age function

```
df['Age'] = df.apply(lambda row: defect_age(row), axis=1)
```

Write result to CSV

```
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, sep=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

ROW 2511:

```
      Identifier Status      OPENED Resolv closed_on duplicate_on junked_on  \
2511  xxxx5           J  2002-02-07    NaN       NaN          NaN       NaN   

     unproducible_on verified_on  
2511             NaN         NaN
```

Comment: I'd love to help but there are many moving parts in your post.  It's difficult to wrangle what the problem is and where to begin.  If this is a high priority for you, consider redoing your question such that you follow the principles of MCVE.  A link to explain what that is. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I understand that you would like to return the calculations in number of days based on the status of your data, correct? I also understand that you are grouping your DataFrame by something and working with each group. If both of my statements are correct, there is a much easier way to achieve your goal. But let us know so that we don't spin our wheels pointlessly. Also, you will need to edit your question. Please refer to @piRSquared's comment for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I will work on fixing my question.

Hi @Kartik, your assumption is correct.  Sorry about my bad question.  I am pulling several data sources and merging them into one df.  Once I merge them I perform the above date calculation based on the status of the data.

Comment: You still haven't told us what you are trying to do. If you can provide a sample of input data, and a sample of desired output, it'll be of much more help than copy pasting your code here. For example, refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38910438/3765319 Please reframe your question somewhat like that.

Comment: Thanks @Kartik, I added the information you requested.

Comment: if your function is returning none is because in the nested `if-elif` block one of the condition is not fulfilled, add a `else` at the end with a print or something to debug the problem.

Comment: Hi @Copperfield, adding an additional `else` in the nested `if-elif` did not solve the issue.  I couldn't get it to trigger the print.

Comment: well, I testing your code with the first example data I get a error with the "Date calculation by status" part, so moving those part to their respective `if` and it work as expected... so I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @Copperfield what if you delete the date in Resolv column for all rows that have status R?

Comment: I get a type error: `TypeError: ("ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[D]')", 'occurred at index 4')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick code that basically gets the age using the status where if the status is not in the terminal, it will default to date today.

```
def toDateTime(s): return dtt.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')

def defect_age(row):
    status_dict = {'R': 'Resolv', 'V': 'verified_on',
           'D': 'duplicate_on', 'J': 'junked_on',
           'U': 'unproducible_on', 'C': 'closed_on'}

    submitted = toDateTime(row['OPENED'])
    status = row['Status']

    if status in status_dict:
        date_from_col = row[status_dict[status]]
        date = toDateTime(date_from_col) if date_from_col != '' else dtt.today()
    else:
        date = dtt.today()

    return (date - submitted).days
```

This function is equivalent to your defect_age function above. Now, you can then apply this function to your dataframe as

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df['Age'] = df.apply(defect_age, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks!  I get a type error with this but I am working on resolving that.  Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi John, I had time to resolve that error.  Now I have `ValueError: ("time data 'nan' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'", u'occurred at index 2511')`.  Trying to handle 'nan'

Comment: @anshanno, that occurs when the format of the string does not match the given '%Y-%m-%d' format. it's either the df.OPENED or the needed column at index 2511 is nan. I would assume that df.OPENED always have a consistent format so it must be from the needed column. In that case, we should add a filter for the case that date is 'nan'

Comment: Hi John, shouldn't that be caught in this line? `date = toDateTime(date_from_col) if date_from_col != 'nan' else dtt.today()`

Comment: yep. to include both cases when date is nan or '', you might want to do: `date = toDateTime(date_from_col) if date_from_col not in ['nan', ''] else dtt.today()`

Comment: Hi John, I got the same error so I tried to use `date = pd.to_datetime(date_from_col) if date_from_col != pd.NaT else dtt.today()` and now I am getting `AttributeError: ("'NaTType' object has no attribute 'days'", u'occurred at index 2511')`  I am utterly confused.

Comment: I just included it above in my initial question so it would be easier to read.  I noticed it was giving `NaN` but its calling it a `NaT` so I tried `pd.NaN` and it was still no good.

Comment: how about this: `date = toDateTime(date_from_col) if (date_from_col != '' or not np.isnan(date_from_col)) else dtt.today()`

Comment: Same error :(.  This is the issue I was having with my bad conditional statement above.  The NaN values were not triggering anything in the conditional statement. 

`ValueError: ("time data 'nan' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'", u'occurred at index 2511')`

Comment: could you add this code after you load your data into df: `df.fillna('', inplace=True)`. That piece of code will replace of NaN in your date with '' so that you will have uniform code for missing values. after that, revert the line with `date` into `date = toDateTime(date_from_col) if date_from_col != '' else dtt.today()`.

Comment: `df.fillna('', inplace=True)` worked!  That was one of the first things I tried, but I didn't include `inplace=True`.  Thank you so much :)